# Having issues toggling multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

My issue is this, I have three separate sections in my page that show examples of products/ services, what I need though is to add a toggle div underneath each particular section that can show further details on the product, but the other perviously revealed sections must close when the anchor is clicked.

An example can be seen here: http://www.bamboohr.com/tour.php.

I want to replicate the way in-which the div reveals further info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code:

-container-

-section id="services"-

-div-

-a href=""--/a- (!-=== anchor that will open the div ===-)

-/div-

-div--/div-(!-=== div that will open ===-)

-/section-

-section id="services"-

-div-

-a href=""--/a- (!-=== anchor that will open the div ===-)

-/div-

-div--/div-(!-=== div that will open ===-)

-/section-

-section id="services"-

-div-

-a href=""--/a- (!-=== anchor that will open the div ===-)

-/div-

-div--/div-(!-=== div that will open ===-)

-/section-

-/container-

Comment: Is that your website? How about trying to extract a less complicated example for purposes of your question?

Comment: and you formatting looks  weird...

Comment: i couldnt figure out how to post html

Comment: add your HTML code... select the codes and press ctrl+k .. and that should formatt the codes.. try it out

Answer (score 0):

You use utilize the [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) functionality of jQuery

Try out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/34NkE/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">Click div1</div>
<div class="toggle_div">this is the content of toggle div 1</div>
<div class="box">Click div2</div>
<div class="toggle_div">this is the content of toggle div 2</div>
<div class="box">Click div3</div>
<div class="toggle_div">this is the content of toggle div 3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.toggle_div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    $('.active').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).next('div').addClass('active').slideToggle("slow")
});
```